# What does T == T mean in the struct SinkOf implementation? (swift)

Tags: swift, generics

Anybody can help with this? Here is the quote from swift standard library.

```
/// A type-erased sink.
///
/// Forwards operations to an arbitrary underlying sink with the same
/// `Element` type, hiding the specifics of the underlying sink type.
struct SinkOf<T> : SinkType {

    /// Construct an instance whose `put(x)` calls `putElement(x)`
    init(_ putElement: (T) -> ())

    /// Construct an instance whose `put(x)` calls `base.put(x)`
    init<S : SinkType where T == T>(_ base: S)

    /// Write `x` to this sink.
    func put(x: T)
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comments to the referenced thread, this is just a bug in the auto-generated headers. I think that has been fixed in Swift 2.